# vim auto save current file when focus is lost

Tags: vim

How to make vim automatically save only current buffer when focus is lost, not all files as described here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_save_files_when_focus_is_lost

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments I can say that you have wrong question: you want not to *“save only current buffer when focus is lost”* (focus tends to have a meaning of “currently focused window”), but to “write buffer when switching to another one: when it is no longer in your focus *of attention*”. To complete this you may use

```
augroup AutoWrite
    autocmd! BufLeave * :update
augroup END
```

, maybe combined with

```
set autowrite
```

and

```
set autowriteall
```

(sets of situations where first and second two variants are triggered intersect, but neither is a superset of another one).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `:wa` (write all), use `:w`.

Comment: @milushov Wondering whether you are using terminal vim. If yes, forget about this idea or use gvim instead.

Comment: @ZyX i use gvim, btw there is my vimrc file - https://github.com/milushov/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc#L275

Comment: By the way, use `:update` in place of `:write`: this one won’t save file if it did not change.

Comment: @milushov There is `:wa`, not `:write` (as @sidyll suggested) or `:update`. Also, what means “is not working” (i.e. what you observe)?

Comment: @milushov [Here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) is the description why you should not be using `:map` without `nore` in your vimrc.

Comment: @milushov “Not working” is *completely* useless statement to anybody willing to help. You should say how did you test and what did you observe. Maybe you just forgot to rerun vim or modify file.

Comment: @ZyX thanks for this link; i observe nothing when i toggle buffers; sorry, i forgot to update repo;

Comment: @milushov *Toggle buffers*? This (`FocusLost`) is event for the case when you switch from GVim window to something else (e.g. browser or terminal). For switching between GVim windows you should use `WinLeave`, for switching between GVim tabs use `TabLeave` (not really needed as `WinLeave` is launched prior to this) and `BufLeave` for really toggling buffers (launched before `WinLeave` or `TabLeave`). You are likely needing the latter in place of `FocusLost`. Or, maybe `FocusLost,BufLeave`.

Comment: You may also want to look on `set autowrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try this

```
set updatetime=1000
autocmd CursorHoldI * silent w
```

just put it in your .vimrc